# One-liner for variable space indentation

Tags: java, string, indentation

In a "pretty print" function for a nested map, I need a simple indent function to prepend the needed space to my structure.
I wanted a simple one-liner and the best I found was a 2 line solution. 
Ideally, I wanted this:

```
String indentSpace = new String(Arrays.fill(new char[indent], 0, indent-1, ' '));
```

That doesn't work because Arrays.fill is not 'fluent'; it returns void.

A literal translation of that expression is too verbose for my liking:

```
char[] chars = new char[indent];
Arrays.fill(chars , ' ');
String indentSpace = new String(chars);
```

Finally, I settled for a lack-lustre 2-line solution:

```
private final String indentSpace="                                                     ";
...
String alternative = indentSpace.substring(0,indent % indentSpace.length());
```

This is minor nit-picking, but I remained curious on whether there's a more elegant solution. I recon that the last option might be a good choice performance-wise.

Any takes?

Comment: There's useful stuff in apache commons to help with this, see the `StringUtils` class

Comment: Or may be you can write your own utility method to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following one-liner should work:

```
String indentSpace  = new String(new char[indent]).replace('\0', ' ');
```

Answer (score 5):

If indeed line count is your primary measurement then this is a compact way to create a `String` with `n` spaces:

```
String spaces = n == 0 ? "" : String.format("%" + n + "s", "");
```

Performance is probably not so great.

Comment: Line count the 'primary' concern, but certainly not the only one :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a string with just spaces in it then [StringUtils.repeat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) will work:

```
String indentSpace = StringUtils.repeat(' ', indent);
```

Comment: `leftPad` doesn't actually pad a string with an indent, instead it ensures the returned string is at least *n* chars long (where *n* is `indent` in your example).